# How do I force only one instance of my application?

Tags: application-development, python, indicator, quickly

I am developing a program using quickly. I am using an indicator which can hide/show the main window.

But when I launch the application from the launcher it starts a new instance of that application (so an additional indicator will be shown). Rather than just showing the main window of the previous running app.

What's the usual way of forcing only one indicator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure you have a good reason to do this. People expect applications to work as you describe in your post. Even though you personally might not like it.

But, to answer your question, one of the easiest ways to do it is by making a file (for example in the configuration directory) at startup, which you remove when your application exits. Before starting the application, you check in your code if another instance is already active, and if so, you exit directly. If you also want to focus the active application, you need a way to do inter process communication. For example via a socket. See http://docs.python.org/library/ipc.html for more info.

Comment: I would add that you should put your application's process ID in that file, then not only check that the file exists, but check that the process exists and matches your application.  Otherwise a force-quit of your application may leave behind the file even when it's not running.

Answer (score 2):

I have found an even better solution (little more complicated though). You can verify not only whether your process is running but also provide some input to it if it's already launched. Please check out [this solution](http://lethalman.blogspot.fi/2008/11/single-app-instances-python-and-dbus.html) from [Luca Bruno](https://www.blogger.com/profile/06329046616630750783):

> [I'm working on](http://lethalman.blogspot.com/2008/10/freespeak-gtkgnome-translator.html) [FreeSpeak](https://web.archive.org/web/20080403055601/http://home.gna.org/freespeak/) lately and I needed to run the application once per session, as it's got a trayicon and a notebook (maybe windows with an applet is better?)
> I decided to use [DBus](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/) for making the application run only a single instance; when you try to open it again it won't start another process, instead it will use the already running one.
>
> This is how I would create a generic single app instance with dbus-python:
>
> ```
> import dbus
> import dbus.bus
> import dbus.service
> import dbus.mainloop.glib
> import gobject
>
> class Application (dbus.service.Object):
>   def __init__ (self, bus, path, name):
>     dbus.service.Object.__init__ (self, bus, path, name)
>     self.loop = gobject.MainLoop ()
>
>  @dbus.service.method ("org.domain.YourApplication",
>                        in_signature='a{sv}', out_signature='')
>  def start (self, options={}):
>    if self.loop.is_running ():
>      print 'instance already running'
>    else:
>      self.loop.run ()
>
> dbus.mainloop.glib.DBusGMainLoop (set_as_default=True)
> bus = dbus.SessionBus ()
> request = bus.request_name ("org.domain.YourApplication", dbus.bus.NAME_FLAG_DO_NOT_QUEUE)
> if request != dbus.bus.REQUEST_NAME_REPLY_EXISTS:
>  app = Application (bus, '/', "org.domain.YourApplication")
> else:
>  object = bus.get_object ("org.domain.YourApplication", "/")
>  app = dbus.Interface (object, "org.domain.YourApplication")
>
> # Get your options from the command line, e.g. with OptionParser
> options = {'option1': 'value1'}
> app.start (options)
> ```
>
> **How it works?**
>
> 1. Setup the mainloop for dbus
> 2. Request a session bus name, so that other applications (in our case another instance of the same application) can connect to it
> 3. Create a new instance at path / if the bus name doesn't exist (so we are the primary owner). If it exists, then obtain the object from dbus and call the method on the remote Application object using the known interface.
> 4. The Application.start method checks if it's already running then decide what to do in both situations.
>
> Creating a GTK+ application this way is really easy. It only needs to use the GTK+ mainloop.
> Let's suppose we want to present() the GtkWindow when the user tries to open another instance of the application:
>
> ```
> import dbus
> import dbus.bus
> import dbus.service
> import dbus.mainloop.glib
> import gobject
> import gtk
> import gtk.gdk
> import time
>
> class Application (dbus.service.Object):
>  def __init__ (self, bus, path, name):
>    dbus.service.Object.__init__ (self, bus, path, name)
>    self.running = False
>    self.main_window = gtk.Window ()
>    self.main_window.show_all ()
>
>  @dbus.service.method ("org.domain.YourApplication",
>                        in_signature='', out_signature='b')
>  def is_running (self):
>    return self.running
>
>  @dbus.service.method ("org.domain.YourApplication",
>                        in_signature='a{sv}i', out_signature='')
>  def start (self, options, timestamp):
>    if self.is_running ():
>      self.main_window.present_with_time (timestamp)
>    else:
>      self.running = True
>      gtk.main ()
>      self.running = False
>
> dbus.mainloop.glib.DBusGMainLoop (set_as_default=True)
> bus = dbus.SessionBus ()
> request = bus.request_name ("org.domain.YourApplication", dbus.bus.NAME_FLAG_DO_NOT_QUEUE)
> if request != dbus.bus.REQUEST_NAME_REPLY_EXISTS:
>  app = Application (bus, '/', "org.domain.YourApplication")
> else:
>  object = bus.get_object ("org.domain.YourApplication", "/")
>  app = dbus.Interface (object, "org.domain.YourApplication")
>
> # Get your options from the command line, e.g. with OptionParser
> options = {'option1': 'value1'}
> app.start (options, int (time.time ()))
> if app.is_running ():
>  gtk.gdk.notify_startup_complete ()
> ```
>
> **How it works?**
>
> Let's say we're running the Application for the first time, the loop begins and when it ends **running** is set to False, so gtk.gdk.notify_startup_complete() won't be called. Instead, if the application is already running, start() will be called on the remote object running the loop. The method then returns immediately so gtk.gdk.notify_startup_complete() will be called.
> If you don't notify to the launcher that the startup is complete... guess what happens to your mouse and to your taskbar panel...
>
> If the loop is running, the window is presented to the user with a little delay. If you don't use any timestamp, the UI interaction won't let the window have the time to be presented.
>
> Of course, you can use DBus for many more things, like both setting options from the command line, as explained in the above code, and let other applications communicate with yours and viceversa.
> Nowadays almost all systems use DBus, so it won't be a pain to add such dependency. In my opinion, it would be much more painful to use lock files, FIFO, unix sockets or whatever. FreeSpeak used such old technologies and it was a very poor emulation of what DBus already offers.