# Force one instance per workspace of an application

Tags: nautilus, workspaces, multiple-instances

Ubuntu 14.04 uses Files to browse files. If I open a new folder (either with Launchy or clicking on a folder in the Desktop), I want it is open in a new tab. Right now, it is opened in a new separated window/instance.

A solution could be download the source code and [modify it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155496/how-do-i-force-only-one-instance-of-my-application). Is there a simpler/quicker solution? Maybe another alternative to Files?

Comment: Nautilus doesn't have the option to open a new tab from command line.

Comment: So the only solution is to modify the source code. Is it right @JacobVlijm? Maybe there is an already modified version of Nautilus. Maybe there is a quite similar application to Nautilus which offer that functionality.

Comment: Similar question https://askubuntu.com/questions/55656/open-nautilus-as-new-tab-in-existing-window

Comment: You're right @Sneetsher, but the answer is from 2012. Do you think it is still working?